# Removal of bounty from a Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, bounties

Can I remove a bounty which I set on a question if none of the answers satisfy me?

Answer (score 9):

No.

From the bounties [help center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

**All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

Comment: If I answer my own question!!!

Comment: @Saty you can't award a bounty to your answer.

Comment: **under any circumstances** means exactly that. You pay to "advertise" your question. You don't get the payment back.

Comment: @Saty: Think of it like putting an ad in the newspaper. (What a quaint idea!) You pay for the ad regardless. The newspaper doesn't refund the fee if you don't get any sales.

Comment: Well, there are exceptions, e.g. if the question is off topic and should be closed, or if the bounty was started by innocent mistake... but those are rare edge cases.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. The rep that you lost for that bounty can't be refunded. Either you'll award it to some answer or the system will auto award half of it to the best new answer having a score of at least +2. If no such answer exists, the bounty is not awarded, and the bounty rep is lost.

Comment: What about the third option if none of the answer exist with +2 then will that be credited to my account?

Comment: @Saty it'll just disappear.

Comment: @Saty The rep will never be refunded to your account. It doesn't matter if somebody else gets it or not.

Comment: Thanks all !!!!So I just lost 50 points for nothing...I put the question and added bounty and then I came up with answer!!!!!!!

Comment: @Saty It's only rep points. It doesn't mean much. Besides that, it's possible that the extra visibility that the bounty brought to your question gave it some upvotes it wouldn't have gotten otherwise. And if no one answered your question to your satisfaction and you found the correct answer yourself, you can post your own answer.